# jQuery If DIV Doesn't Have Class "x"

Tags: jquery

In jQuery I need to do an if statement to see if $this doesn't contain the class '.selected'.

```
$(".thumbs").hover(function(){

$(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
},function(){
$(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

});
```

Basically when this function is run (on hover) I don't want to perform the fades if the class '.selected' has been appended to the div, this will mean that the image will be at full opacity to signify that it's selected. Searched on Google to no luck even though it's a simple question of how to use an IF statement...

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Use the ["not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector)" selector.

For example, instead of:

`$(".thumbs").hover()`

try:

`$(".thumbs:not(.selected)").hover()`

Comment: thinking about it, if the OP is adding the class to the div at some point after document.ready then I don't think your syntax will work

Comment: @zuk1: Well, from your snippet, you take all elements with class 'thumb' and do a hover() on each one. Are you saying you want to just do hover on one element? WHat is that one element? I am confused.

Comment: @Russ: Correct. If you use the above, then it will take all elems currently in the DOM at the time it is executed, and to those with class 'thumb' and not 'selected' it will do hover().

Comment: If you need to do this outside of the selector for some reason, you can use `.not( ".selected" )` and it'll work the same. Brilliant stuff.

Answer (score 191):

jQuery has the hasClass() function that returns true if any element in the wrapped set contains the specified class

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

[Take a look at my example of use](http://jsbin.com/ugaxe)

- If you hover over a div, it fades as
  normal speed to 100% opacity if the
  div does not contain the 'selected'
  class
- If you hover out of a div, it fades
  at slow speed to 30% opacity if the
  div does not contain the 'selected'
  class
- Clicking the button adds 'selected'
  class to the red div. The fading
  effects no longer work on the red div

Here is the code for it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #FFF; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
</style>


<!-- jQuery code here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('#myButton').click(function(e) {
$('#div2').addClass('selected');
});

$('.thumbs').bind('click',function(e) { alert('You clicked ' + e.target.id ); } );

$('.thumbs').hover(fadeItIn, fadeItOut);


});

function fadeItIn(e) {
if (!$(e.target).hasClass('selected')) 
 { 
    $(e.target).fadeTo('normal', 1.0); 
  } 
}

function fadeItOut(e) { 
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('selected'))
  { 
    $(e.target).fadeTo('slow', 0.3); 
 } 
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" class="thumbs" style=" background-color: #0f0; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; width: 100px; height: 50px; clear: both;"> 
One div with a thumbs class
</div>
<div id="div2" class="thumbs" style=" background-color: #f00; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; width: 100px; height: 50px; clear: both;">
Another one with a thumbs class
</div>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="add 'selected' class to red div" />
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

this is just a guess, but are you trying to [achieve something like this](http://jsbin.com/adana)?

- Both divs start at 30% opacity
- Hovering over a div fades to 100% opacity, hovering out fades back to 30% opacity. Fade effects only work on elements that don't have the 'selected' class
- Clicking a div adds/removes the
  'selected' class

jQuery Code is here-

```
$(function() {

$('.thumbs').bind('click',function(e) { $(e.target).toggleClass('selected'); } );
$('.thumbs').hover(fadeItIn, fadeItOut);
$('.thumbs').css('opacity', 0.3);

});

function fadeItIn(e) {
if (!$(e.target).hasClass('selected')) 
 { 
    $(e.target).fadeTo('normal', 1.0); 
  } 
}

function fadeItOut(e) { 
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('selected'))
  { 
    $(e.target).fadeTo('slow', 0.3); 
 } 
}

<div id="div1" class="thumbs" style=" background-color: #0f0; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; width: 100px; height: 50px; clear: both; cursor:pointer;"> 
One div with a thumbs class
</div>
<div id="div2" class="thumbs" style=" background-color: #f00; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; width: 100px; height: 50px; clear: both; cursor:pointer;">
Another one with a thumbs class
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work for some reason :(

$(".thumbs").hover(function(){

if (!($(this).hasClass(".selected")){

$(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
},function(){
$(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

}

});

and it breaks my entire code, none of the JS works with that added

Comment: does hasClass require the .?  hasClass('selected') instead of hasClass('.selected')

Comment: Russ' example may work if you use "selected" instead of ".selected"?

Comment: apologies, didn't mean to put the . in there. Updated now

Comment: I've added some examples to my answer, to show the code working

Answer (score 30):

I think the author was looking for:

```
$(this).not('.selected')
```

Comment: Was not expecting this to work. Even works like  $(".class1").not(".class2") which is exactly what I was after! Thanks!

Comment: It works, but it's worth noting that this doesn't work as a boolean, as it returns an array. Empty arrays are "truthy" in Javascript. You could use `$(this).not('.selected').length` as a boolean if you really wanted to, but that's a little verbose.

Answer (score 5):

When you are checking if an element has or does not have a class, make sure you didn't accidentally put a dot in the class name:

```
<div class="className"></div>

$('div').hasClass('className');
$('div').hasClass('.className'); #will not work!!!!
```

After a long time of staring at my code I realized I had done this. A little typo like this took me an hour to figure out what I had done wrong. Check your code!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumbs").hover(
    function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
        }
    },
    function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.3); 
        }           
    }
);
```

Putting an if inside of each part of the hover will allow you to change the select class dynamically and the hover will still work.

```
$(".thumbs").click(function() {
    $(".thumbs").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
            $(this).hover();
        }
    });                 
    $(this).addClass("selected");                   
});
```

As an example I've also attached a click handler to switch the selected class to the clicked item. Then I fire the hover event on the previous item to make it fade out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the addClass and removeClass methods to toggle between items such as tabs.

e.g.

```
if($(element).hasClass("selected"))
   $(element).removeClass("selected");
```

Comment: why not just use toggleClass()?

Comment: Because the element might have other classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using an if inside the event, you unbind the event when the select class is applied?
I'm guessing you add the class inside your code somewhere, so unbinding the event there would look like this:

```
$(element).addClass( 'selected' ).unbind( 'hover' );
```

The only downside is that if you ever remove the selected class from the element, you have to subscribe it to the hover event again.