# jQuery If Div Does NOT Exist

Tags: jquery

I have 3 images and have a function so that on mouse rollover they fade in and out. I don't want to do this if the image being rolled over has the class 'selected'.

So far I have this code:

```
$(".thumbs").hover(function(){

if (!($(this).hasClass(".selected")){

$(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
},function(){
$(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

}

});
```

to me the IF statement looks like it should be:

```
if (!($(this).hasClass(".selected"))){
```

but neither work so who knows. When I implement this code my entire javascript stops working, any ideas why?

There is virtually NO information on IF statements for jQuery on Google, it's ridiculous. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520250/jquery-if-div-doesnt-have-class-x

Comment: People couldn't answer it so I asked again, now it's been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The jQuery docs on selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) tells you everything you neeed to know.

```
$('.thumbs:not(.selected)').hover(function(){
  // ...
})
```

Comment: I think this would not work if the selected item changed (assuming you called this in $(document).ready)

Comment: I agree that this wouldn't work if called in document ready if the selected class were applied after page load.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your element has the class "selected" not ".selected". Remove the dot.

Comment: jQuery uses CSS-like notation for its selectors… the dot indicates that it is a class.

Comment: @Ben: $(".selected") is correct but the OP wants hasClass("selected").  Note the first is a selctor the second is not.

Comment: this is what happens when people learn jQuery instead of JS :(

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr) function:

```
if ($(this).not(".selected")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be

```
if (!($(this).hasClass("selected"))){
```

no . because it knows you're looking for a classname.

Answer (score 1):

I think your javascript isn't properly formatted -- braces in the wrong places -- and you shouldn't use the dot in the hasClass function.  A little better formatting would help readability, too.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.thumbs').hover( function() {
                            if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                                $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
                            }
                        },
                        function() {
                            $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
                        }
                 );
});
```