# How to test a DIV to see if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I'm using Drupal as a CMS for a client, and they have a specific request.  They want a navigation type bar to show up on the left hand side that displays the information about their college programs.  However, if they field doesn't contain any information, they don't want the link to show up.

So, my question is, how would I test the div CLASS to see if it exists, and then show or hide the corresponding link?

Here is my code:

```
<script>

if ($('.testimonials').length) 
{
    $('#testimon').show();
}
else
{
    $('#testimon').hide();
}   
</script>
<a href="#" id="descrip">Program Description</a><br />
<a href="#" id="admis">Admission Requirements</a><br />
<a href="#" id="career">Career Opportunities</a><br />
<a href="#" id="co_op">Co-Op Diploma</a><br />
<a href="#" id="outcomes">Program Outcomes</a><br />
<a href="#" id="struc">Program Structure</a><br />
<a href="#" id="testimon">Student Testimonials</a><br />
<a href="#" id="transfer">Transferability</a><br />
<a href="#" id="tuition">Tuition and Fees</a><br />
```

The div I am testing for is given the following class:  `<div class="testimonials">`

Currently, the "Student Testimonials" contains no information, so the div is actually hidden.  It doesn't even show up if it doesn't contain anything.

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT EDIT EDIT

My apologies, the DIV is not hidden, it's just not populated at all.  So, instead of the div showing up, there is actually nothing.  It skips that field, and proceeds on to "Transferability".

EDIT EDIT EDIT

Perhaps it will help if you see the code inside the page:

```
<div class="main_top">

  Business Administration - Business
</div>
<div class="prog_descrip">
  <label>Program description:</label>
    ....SOME CODE....
</div>
<div class="admin_req">
  <label>Admission Requirements:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClassF9C2869A55724649B235CB0F312F44EA">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="career_opp">
  <label>Career Opportunities:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClass86EA926232844F31914AB54479958286">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="co_op_diploma">
  <label>Co-Op Diploma:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClass921A20DCA14344B4A5B8C320CBBCCAC2">
    ....SOME CODE....
   </div>
</div>
<div class="prog_out">
  <label>Program Outcomes:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClass2964EBDD55244ABDB4DB35FBCC3DF19F">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="prog_struc">
  <label>Program Structure:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClassDE705C7CFB1149ED8C164122009A235E">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="transfer">
  <label>Transferability:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClass7A18D2A8B34D458C89E330E9C6FF4B61">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tuition">
  <label>Tuition And Fees:</label>
  <div class="ExternalClassC8C745D8B6FA46F9B3E20E6AC95D0933">
    ....SOME CODE....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is unclear to me, your code, more or less checks for this already.

Comment: John - check my edit.  Basically, what happens is that the div doesn't even get printed to the screen.  So, the div isn't there.  So, I want to check and see if the div EXISTS... If it has no content, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I modified my answer below.  It now checks that the element exists AND that it has content.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just wrapping the code you already have in the document ready snippet will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

      if ($('.testimonials').length) 
      {
          $('#testimon').show();
      }
      else
      {
          $('#testimon').hide();
      }   

 });
```

Just put that code in the head of your HTML page inside a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) takes a boolean (show/hide)

```
  $('#testimon').toggle($('.testimonials:not(:empty)').length);
```

Comment: This also does not work.  I'm not trying to toggle the link, I don't want the link to show up at all if there is no div.

Comment: John, this is not what I'm looking for.  I tried toggle(), hide() and show(), and none of them changed anything.  I tried to hide it with CSS, and it hid it fine (the link).  However, I think there's a failure with how I'm testing the logic.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$("div:first-child")
```

Comment: What is the div:first-child going to do?  Do you mean div:testimonials?

Comment: Ah either your post was edited a lot or I misunderstood. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520481/jquery-if-div-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

If the DIV is there but hidden because it has no content, you can try

```
$(".testimonials").is(':visible')
```

Comment: No, the div isn't there at all.  I need to test and see if it IS there, because if it is, that's when I need the link to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'll need a reusable function as well:

`function isHidden(elm,target) {
    // if whether it is non-existent, or hidden via css
    if (elm.length===0 || elm.is(":hidden")) { 
        target.hide();
    }
}

var elm = $(".testimonials"), target = $("#testimon");
isHidden(elm,target);`

A sample of this script @ http://jsfiddle.net/99d6e/

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly as you said, and it does not work.  The div does not show up if it doesn't have content.  It's display is not set to none, it just doesn't populate the div at all.