# How to get value from the first checkbox which is not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to get the value from a checkbox which is not hidden.

Here is my HTML & JQuery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var maanu = $('.form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').filter(':first').val();

  alert(maanu);

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <input class="bills hide" type="checkbox" value="01" checked="checked" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills" type="checkbox" value="02" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills" type="checkbox" value="03" checked="checked" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills " type="checkbox" value="04" checked="checked" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills " type="checkbox" value="05" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills " type="checkbox" value="06" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills " type="checkbox" value="07" />
  <br />
  <input class="bills " type="checkbox" value="08" />
  <br />
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/xgQVG/5/)**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked:visible:first').val();
```

Comment: Alternatively:  `$('input:checkbox:checked:visible:eq(0)').val();` or `$('input:checkbox:checked:visible')[0].val();` though the array approach may fail without a check first.  Does anyone know if `:first` is slower than `:eq(0)`?

Comment: @lucuma The array approach will throw a syntax error, as it returns the actual DOM element (which has no `.val()` function) rather than a jQuery object containing the single element.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Good catch. Monday morning brain fart.  The array approach needs to return `.value`

Comment: And, in terms of efficiency, I found this existing [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-vs-eq-0-vs-0/2) that indicates using the array approach - `$('input:checkbox:checked:visible')[0].value;` - would be the fastest. Though whether or not it's going to matter in most cases, I couldn't say.

Answer (score 2):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/xgQVG/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var maanu = $('.form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked:not(:hidden)').filter(':first').val();

    alert(maanu);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, and is very easy to read and understand:

```
$('input').not('.hide').first().val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer. I think it may help you answer your question
[jQuery If DIV Doesn't Have Class "x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520250/jquery-if-div-doesnt-have-class-x)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('.form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not('.hide').filter(':first').val();
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgQVG/7/).