# Can't make the if else jquery statement work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added the code to the js below. When you click on either the Sign up or Login the arrow moves / point up, but when you close it again it stay that way. Can someone help me out figure what to do.

I tried using this post but cant make this work either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520250/jquery-if-div-doesnt-have-class-x)

Here is the Jquery script I use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
            $('#login-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b2;');

            $('#signup-content').slideUp();
        })
        $('#signup-trigger').click(function () {
            $('#login-content').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b2;');

            $('#signup-content').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pd6sW/), ( I know some people don't pref jsfiddle but since I have a lot of code and it will be so much easier to show what I'm trying to do with it)

Comment: you are missing else part , change it back to down arrow in elese

Comment: It might be easier to test and demonstrate in a jsFiddle right now but StackOverflow will probably outlive jsFiddle and then all of these questions become useless for future visitors. You could have cut out the majority of your code into what is actually required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the problem is** since you are adding the class active to it, on click event .. and right after, you are checking if it has a class active(which is always true)...

use `toggleClass`(it toggles the mentioned class) instead of `addClass` and check with `hasClass`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
         $('#login-content').slideToggle();
         $(this).toggleClass('active');
         if ($(this).hasClass('active')){              
             $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b2;');
        }else{
           $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;'); 

        }
        $('#signup-content').slideUp();
     });
    .... //same for signup
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pd6sW/4/)

and yes `I know some people don't pref jsfiddle` .. i guess you are wrong , i am sure most people prefer jsfiddle  rather than the code itself since it is easier to test in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You missed else part.

Try:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b2;');
}
else{
    $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b0;');//code of down arrow
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pd6sW/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the class active, so after the first click it looks like it is always active, and you also never change the triangle shape after the first click.

This code should work for the login:

```
$('#login-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#login-content').slideToggle();


        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) { //Now is not active, I'll make it active
            $(this).addClass('active');    //Add class
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25b2;');  //BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
        } else { //Now is active, I'll make it not active
            $(this).removeClass('active');  //Remove class
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');  //BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
        }

       $('#signup-content').slideUp();
    })
```

This is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eC6u6/).