# jQuery addClass( ) prepend( ) Run only once

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that is unfortunately being called everytime a new row is added to a table which is on the same page.

I'd like to use jQuery to make this run only once. I looked at "One" but couldn't find a suitable trigger to tie it to eg click, scroll

```
$(".fieldname").addclass("classname").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this by only applying the function if the element in question did not have the class which I was adding. I did it using the jQuery [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/#selector) - [explained best here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520250/jquery-if-div-doesnt-have-class-x) function which is pretty cool.

```
$(".fieldname:not(.classname)").addclass("classname").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");
```

Comment: $(".fieldname:not(.classname)").addClass("classname").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");      addclass("classname") should be addClass("classname").

Answer (score 2):

Set a global variable somewhere:

```
var run = false;
```

And then run it behind a conditional inside of that method thats being called and set it to true:

```
if (!run) {
  $(".fieldname").addclass("classname").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");

  run = true;
}
```

Preferably, this would be behind a namespace like `myApp.run` and not directly in the window object.

`...`

Edit for **your** specific case (mind you this is pretty hacky code)...

```
if (!window.run) {
  $(".fieldname").addclass("classname").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");

  window.run = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, unfortunately it's not working for me. I prob should have mentioned I'm working in Drupal so the jQuery is called like so: Drupal.behaviors.editFormTableAddButton = {
   attach: function (context, settings) {
    var run = false;
    if (!run) {
      $(".field-add-more-submit").removeClass("btn-info").addClass("btn-primary btn-sm").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> ");
     run = true;
    }
   }
 };

Comment: I've updated a way to do it in your situation. However, I see you've figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

check if it `hasClass` or not :

```
var elem = $(".fieldname"),
    className = "class";
if(!elem.hasClass(className)){
    elem.addClass(className).prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");
}
```