# How to select items without a specific class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to select all items that have the class .me-item-admin-box but doesn't have the class .me-item-unenabled

ie:

```
<div class='me-item-admin-box'>select this</div>
<div class='me-item-admin-box mi-item-unenabled'>don't select this</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$('.me-item-admin-box').not('.me-item-unenabled').addClass('.me-item-unenabled');
```

but this doesn't work. How would I do this?

## Edit

This is a bit of a simplification of what I need to do. I'm aware I could add this class to everything but I do need to select this class which doesn't have this other class.

Comment: Side note, `addClass('.me-item-unenabled')` should be `addClass('me-item-unenabled')`

Comment: Also, is it `me-item-unenabled` or `mi-item-unenabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select only the elements that are missing the class.  If you want to ensure that all elements with `.me-item-admin-box` also have `.mi-item-unenabled`, just add the class to the selected elements:

```
$('.me-item-admin-box').addClass('me-item-unenabled');
```

There's no need to deselect elements that don't already have `.me-item-unenabled`.  The class will be added where it can be added.

In the case that you want to select any element without `.someClass`, you can use the `:not()` selector.

```
$(':not(.someClass)').addClass('otherClass');
```

Comment: ok, so my question is a bit of a simplified example of the real-world scenario. I really do need to select all items that don't have a particular class.

Comment: @timpone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520250/jquery-if-div-doesnt-have-class-x

Comment: thx @j08691 , works well